# Erro ao salvar dados no banco de dados Sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

O create table funciona, mas ao colocar o codigo para salvar, a aplicação compila mas não salva. O que pode ser?

```
SQLiteDatabase winlife;
EditText edt_meta;
EditText edt_tempo;
EditText edt_dataExpiracao;

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listagem);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

    winlife = openOrCreateDatabase( "winlife.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
    winlife.setVersion(3);
    winlife.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());

    String criaTabelaMetas = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS metas (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, descricao TEXT, tempoRealizacao INTEGER, dataExpiracao INTEGER)";
    winlife.execSQL(criaTabelaMetas);

    edt_meta = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_meta);
    edt_tempo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_tempo);
    edt_dataExpiracao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_dataExpiracao);


    Button bt_salvar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_salvar);
    bt_salvar.setOnClickListener(this);

    Cursor cur = winlife.rawQuery("SELECT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM metas)", null);

    if (cur != null) {
        cur.moveToFirst();
        if (cur.getInt (0) == 0) {
            Intent it = new Intent(this,PrimeiraActivity.class);
            startActivity(it);
            finish();
        } else {
            // Tabela ja contem dados.
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()== R.id.bt_salvar) {
        String nomeMeta = edt_meta.getText().toString();
        //String tempoMeta = edt_tempo.getText().toString();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("descricao", nomeMeta);
        //values.put("tempoRealizacao", tempoMeta);

        winlife.insert("metas", "", values);
    }
}



@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
              .replace(R.id.container,  placeholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
            .commit();
  }

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section1);
            break;
        case 2:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section2);
            break;
        case 3:
            mTitle = getString(R.string.title_section3);
            break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.listagem, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((ListagemActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(
                getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Acredito que o problema é devido a você passar `""` no parâmetro `nullColumnHack`, passe `null`. O parâmetro `nullColumnHack` só deve ser usado quando você quer inserir um linha vazia, por uma limitação do *sqlite*, não se pode fazer insert's sem passar pelo menos um nome de coluna.

Comment: Testei e não funcionou, continua dando erro!

Comment: manda o erro ai